# Why does my TypeScript function returns true/false in one environment and 1/0 in another?

Tags: typescript, boolean

I have a piece of code similar to this:

```
const executeAndGetStatus = async (): Promise<boolean> => {
    let isValid: boolean;
    try {
        await execute();
        isValid = true;
    } catch (err) {
        isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
};
```

When I execute it locally, the return comes out to be `true`/`false`, but when I deploy it to my QA environment, it returns `1`/`0`.

How can this be?

Comment: because it's minified?

Comment: how are you checking what is being returned?

Comment: I have the endpoint returning an object that looks like { isValid: true }. I see the same result through browser or postman